# LDAP authentication with Java config

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to implement LDAP authentication with Spring Security 4 and Java config.
What is the equivalent of this XML in Java config:

```
    <ldap-authentication-provider>
         <password-compare hash="{ssha}"/>
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PasswordCompareLdapConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void registerAuthentication(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new BaseDigestPasswordEncoder()) 
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot instantiate the type BaseDigestPasswordEncoder"

Comment: I think it is new ShaPasswordEncoder() and have to set setEncodeHashAsBase64(true) for ShaPasswordEncoder.I'll check to see if it works.

Comment: You are probably right. I just pasted a sample annotation config..feel free to update the answer of it works for u